# How to update ends_at field of laravel cashier

Tags: laravel, stripe-payments, laravel-cashier

I want to update ends_at column of subscriptions table. When i use

```
Carbon::now()
```

It update perfectly but when is use

```
Carbon::now()->addCenturies(5);
```

I am face error

```
SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect datetime value: '2520-08-07 11:39:13' for column 'ends_at' at row 1 (SQL: update `subscriptions` set `ends_at` = 2520-08-07 11:39:13, `subscriptions`.`updated_at` = 2020-08-07 11:39:13 where `id` = 1)
```

i want one subscription for life time due to this i think add centuries. kinldy tell me solution my controller code is

```
  $subscription = $user->newSubscription('default', $plan->plan_id)->create($request->paymentMethod, [ 'email' => $user->email ]); 
                $subscription->ends_at = Carbon::now()->addCenturies(5);
                $subscription->save();
```

Comment: The `TIMESTAMP` data type is used for values that contain both date and time parts. `TIMESTAMP` has a range of **'1970-01-01 00:00:01' UTC** to **'2038-01-19 03:14:07' UTC**. Your given year is **2520** and your MySQL can handle year as max **2038**

Comment: Then how can i fix it

Comment: You need to insert below `2038-01-19 03:14:07`

Comment: its mean i can't add more then 2038?

Comment: You can, if you use `DATETIME`,  Its  supported range is `'1000-01-01 00:00:00'` to `'9999-12-31 23:59:59'`. While  `TIMESTAMP` has a range of `'1970-01-01 00:00:01' UTC` to `'2038-01-19 03:14:07' UTC`. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html

Comment: If you are using `$table->timestamp('ends_at');` then change it to `$table->dateTime('ends_at');`.

Comment: thanks this is my answer

Comment: That solved your problem?

Comment: yes thanks again i have later migration and its work fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `TIMESTAMP` data type is used for values that contain both date and time parts. `TIMESTAMP` has a range of `1970-01-01 00:00:01 UTC` to `2038-01-19 03:14:07 UTC`. Your given year is `2520` and your MySQL can handle year as max `2038`. 
Change the migration *timestamp* to *dataTime* format as :

```
$table->timestamp('ends_at');
```

to

```
$table->dateTime('ends_at');
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `ends_at` is meant to be [managed for you](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/billing#cancelling-subscriptions) by Laravel Cashier, not something you modify manually. Reviewing the [source code](https://github.com/laravel/cashier-stripe/search?q=ends_at&unscoped_q=ends_at), it is only updated based on other values, not any parameters. It also is not used to set any parameters in Stripe API requests. The [`cancel_at` parameter](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/update#update_subscription-cancel_at) would seem to most likely mapping.

If you wish to set `cancel_at`, it takes an epoch timestamp (in seconds). As @sta mentioned above, this has a maximum value of `2147483647`, representing [a time in 2038](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem).

Note also that Subscriptions will by default continue in perpetuity, so it is not necessary to set an "end date" 5 centuries from now.